# django-south Error during migrate

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

I am getting the below error when I am trying to use south to migrate in django.

```
Running migrations for sites:
    - Migrating forwards to 0004_initial.
     > sites:0002_initial
    FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE `django_site` (`id`
    nteger AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `domain` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `na
    e` varchar(50) NOT NULL)
    The error was: (1050, "Table 'django_site' already exists")
    ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

    ! Since you have a database that does not support running
    ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
    ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = DROP TABLE `django_site` CASCADE; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: sites:0002_initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  .............

  django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1050, "Table 'django_site' already exists")
```

The similar issue is also open [here](https://github.com/benliles/djangopypi/issues/42).Any solution to this ? The error seems due to Create table statement as discussed in the github issue or there might be other errors.I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you running this on a "clean" database? The SQL error tells you that you already have a table `django_site`.

Comment: Did you see the link...yes i am running on 'clean' db

Comment: Yes, I saw the link. This is not the same issue. You are getting the SQL error "Table 'django_site' already exists" so for some reason that table already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if django version < 1.7

```
python manage.py migrate yourapp --fake
```

else

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

--fake: Records the migration sequence as having been applied, but doesn’t actually run it. -> [more](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/commands.html#options)